# python pygame music load from text file

Tags: python

I've made a music player that uses a list with the name of my songs but it is really annoying so I made a text file with the name of every song in it.
I convert the text to a list, and then i try to load the first song but it just won't load. 
This is my code:

```
SongPath = '/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/'
f = open(SongPath + 'Songs.txt')
Song = f.readlines()
print(SongPath + Song[0])
print('Music Player(Alpha2.2)')
import pygame
from time import sleep
sorted(Song)
CurrentSong = 0
State = 'Playing'
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(SongPath + Song[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play()
print("Songs:")
for i in range(0, len(Song)):
    print(i+1, Song[i])
print('\nStarted auto play on:\n' + Song[CurrentSong])
```

...
There is more code  but it is irrelevant for this question.
But when I load it up it says:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/Toto-Afrika.mp3
Music Player(Alpha2.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/ABC.py", line 13, in <module>
        pygame.mixer.music.load(SongPath + Song[0])
pygame.error:
Couldn't open '/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/Toto-Africa.mp3'
```

Btw the picture didn't upload so I typed it.

Comment: Note that `sorted(Song)` doesn't sort in-place. `Song = sorted(Song)` will make `Song` point to a sorted list. As for the error: are you _absolutely_ sure that this file actually exists under the very same name and in the same directory?

Comment: ForceBru thanks for the tip!

Comment: Try making the path more explicit? Also it's `import`, not `Import`

Comment: Yeah I know my phone starts every sentence with a capital letter automaticly

Comment: Pygame docs say that `mp3` support is "limited," but I can't find anything more specific than that.  Maybe try converting it to a `.wav`?

Comment: Can you copy and paste exactly what the code is instead of typing it from scratch? What is `Song[0]` initialized to?

Comment: @Will I had a list defined before at the top of my programme and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.readlines()` returns a list of strings, each of which has the newline `'\n'` still attached to the end.

So it's actually trying to load `'/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/Toto-Africa.mp3\n'` (look more closely at the original error message rather than your re-typed version: does the closing quote actually appear on the line **below** the filename?)

Try this:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(SongPath + Song[0].strip())
```

Comment: protip:  as a debugging statement, `print(repr(SongPath + Song[0]))` would make such gotchas clearer than just `print(SongPath + Song[0])`